# GCM: don't receive messages when device is off

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

Please i need help. My app receive messages when the app is open or in background, but if i off the device or force close app, all messages never can received when restart the app. I read a lot of things but i don't find anything. Please there are my classes.

1 Someone send me a message. And I receive the message.

2 I force close my app or off my device.

3 Someone send me a message, but my device is off.

4 I put my device on, and restart the app. I dont receive any messages, but if someone send me a new message now, i receive this message.

Only when the app is in Background or front. But when I restart the app after the app is killed, i dont receive the storage messages from gcm.

This is ReceiverClass:

```
public class MSGReceiver  extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
    msgrcv.putExtra("msg", extras.getString("msg"));
    msgrcv.putExtra("fromu", extras.getString("fromu"));
    msgrcv.putExtra("fromname", extras.getString("name"));

    if(extras.getString("fromu")!=null && extras.getString("msg")!=null){
        try{
            SharedPreferences blindDate = context.getSharedPreferences("datosblind",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            ConexionSQLite conexion = new ConexionSQLite(context);
            int id = Integer.parseInt(extras.getString("fromu"));
            int idUser = Integer.parseInt(blindDate.getString("REG_FROM",""));
            int order = conexion.getSize(id, idUser);
            conexion.insertNewMessage(id, extras.getString("msg"), order+1, "false", idUser);
            conexion.insertNewSize(id, order+1, idUser);
        }catch(Exception e){}
    }

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);
    ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),MSGService.class.getName());
    startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
    setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
  }
}
```

This is ServiceClass:

```
public class MSGService extends IntentService {

SharedPreferences prefs;
NotificationCompat.Builder notification;
NotificationManager manager;


public MSGService() {
    super("MSGService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(this);

    String messageType = gcm.getMessageType(intent);
    prefs = getSharedPreferences("datosblind", 0);


    if (!extras.isEmpty()) {

        if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_SEND_ERROR.equals(messageType)) {
            Log.e("L2C","Error");

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_DELETED.equals(messageType)) {
            Log.e("L2C","Error");

        } else if (GoogleCloudMessaging.
                MESSAGE_TYPE_MESSAGE.equals(messageType)) {

            if(!prefs.getString("CURRENT_ACTIVE","").equals(extras.getString("fromu"))) {
                if(prefs.getInt("iniciadaLaSesion", 0)==1)
                    sendNotification(extras.getString("msg"), extras.getString("fromu"), extras.getString("name"));
            }
        }
    }
    MSGReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}

private void sendNotification(String msg,String mobno,String name) {

    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("mobno", mobno);
    args.putString("name", name);
    args.putString("msg", msg);
    Intent chat = new Intent(this, Conversacion.class);
    chat.putExtra("INFO", args);
    notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    notification.setContentTitle(name);
    notification.setContentText(msg);
    notification.setTicker("Blind Date: " + name);
    notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
    notification.setSound(Uri.parse("android.resource://"
            + this.getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.sonidonotificacion));

    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1000,
            chat, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    notification.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    notification.setAutoCancel(true);
    manager =(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    manager.notify(Integer.parseInt(mobno), notification.build()); 
  }
}
```

This is the manifest:

```
<receiver
        android:name="com.expansion.minlove.MSGReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />

            <category android:name="com.expansion.minlove" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service android:name="com.expansion.minlove.MSGService" />
```

And this is the request of Server:

```html
exports.send = function(fromn,fromu,to,msg,callback) {

user.find({mobno: to},function(err,users){
var len = users.length;
if(len == 0){
callback({'response':"Failure"});
}else{
 var to_id = users[0].reg_id;
 var name = users[0].name;

request(
    { method: 'POST', 
    uri: 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Authorization':'key=********mjxGkTrOnH6dE'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
  "registration_ids" : [to_id],
  "data" : {
    "msg":msg,
    "fromu":fromu,
    "name":fromn
  },
})
    }
  , function (error, response, body) {

   callback({'response':"Success"});
    }
  )
}});

}
```

Please i need help. 
I'm gonna go crazy.

Comment: you can add `time_to_live` parameter in your json array to ensure message is live.

Comment: Given that you are receiving the msg in some instances I'd guess the server side of things is fine. On the client side if you are not receiving messages when your app is closed or when you restart your device (which you should be) then it's likely an issue with your wakeful broadcast receiver. I'd suggest using GcmListenerService to handle this. It is the recommended way to receive GCM messages on Android. See example here: https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/blob/master/android/gcm/app/src/main/java/gcm/play/android/samples/com/gcmquickstart/MyGcmListenerService.java

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <category android:name="com.example.gcm" />
            </intent-filter>
```